# Named_scope refactoring to rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring

I have `named_scope :business, :conditions => "processing_time_15_minutes is null"`

how to refactor to rails4 style

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :

```
scope :business, -> { where(processing_time_15_minutes: nil) }
```

Comment: You don't have to show how to do it in Ruby prior to 1.9 since Rails 4.x don't support Ruby < 1.9.0.

Answer (score 1):

```
scope :business, -> { where(processing_time_15_minutes: nil) }
```